# How to show checklist if has checklist after submit in Laravel foreach?

Tags: html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i try to submit form in foreach blade laravel but why it is not checked after submit?

```html
<form method="get" class="form-inline float-left">
   <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="keyword here" value="{{ $keyword }}">
   </div>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav">
      @foreach($menu as $d)
      <li role="presentation">
         <a class="text-capitalize" >
         <input type="checkbox" name="cx[]" value="{{ $d->custom_search_id }}" {!! (is_array(old('cx[]')) and in_array($d->custom_search_id, old('cx[]'))) ? ' checked' : '' !!} > 
         {!! $d->name !!}
         </a>
      </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
   <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="GO!">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: why `method="get"` ? change it to `post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, create some function like this fisrt:

```html
<?php
   function checkCX($id){
   foreach(\Request::input("cx") as $input){
   if($input == $id){
   return true;
   }
   }
   return false;
   }
   ?>
   
<form method="get" class="form-inline float-left">
   <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="keyword here" value="{{ $keyword }}">
   </div>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav">
      @foreach($menu as $d)
      <li role="presentation">
         <a class="text-capitalize" >
         <input type="checkbox" name="cx[]" value="{{ $d->custom_search_id }}" @if(!empty($d->custom_search_id)) {{ checkCX($d->custom_search_id) ? 'checked' : '' }} @else @endif > 
         {!! $d->name !!}
         </a>
      </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
   <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="GO!">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

### ***#CMIW***

```
<form method="get" class="form-inline float-left">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
     <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="keyword here" value="{{ $keyword }}">
  </div>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav">
     @foreach($menu as $d)
     <li role="presentation">
        <a class="text-capitalize" >
           <input type="checkbox" name="cx[]" value="{{ $d->custom_search_id }}" {!! (is_array(old('cx')) and in_array($d->custom_search_id, old('cx'))) ? 'checked' : null !!}>
           {!! $d->name !!}
        </a>
     </li>
     @endforeach
  </ul>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="GO!">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please replace CMIW heading text with something more meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the old input (with multiple values), you should use the input name without the square brackets when checking the old values (not `old('cx[]')` but `old('cx')`, such as:

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav">
      @foreach($menu as $d)
      <li role="presentation">
         <a class="text-capitalize">
         <input type="checkbox" name="cx[]" value="{{ $d->custom_search_id }}" {!! (is_array(old('cx')) and in_array($d->custom_search_id, old('cx'))) ? ' checked' : '' !!} > 
         {!! $d->name !!}
         </a>
      </li>
      @endforeach
  </ul>
```